# TeamSpeak 3 PHP Framework

Tags: php, frameworks, teamspeak, ts3phpframework

I am still learning PHP and it's the first time I am using this library ([TeamSpeak 3 PHP Framework](https://docs.planetteamspeak.com/ts3/php/framework/)), I am trying to return a count of online users in a specific group, I tried a few different ways and no success.

This one, counts all users in the group (including offline users):

```
$admins = 0;
foreach($ts3->serverGroupGetById(12)->clientList() as $client) {
    $admins++;
}
```

So I tried to compare that list with the online users list:

```
$admins = 0;
foreach($ts3->serverGroupGetById(12)->clientList() as $client) {
    if($ts3->clientList($client)) {
        $admins++;
    }
}
```

And it works sometimes, I say sometimes because I tried it on my virtual server and no issues, the count was right, but when I tried it on another virtual server (I changed the group ID and port) I get this:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '9' in C:\xampp\htdocs\serverstatus\libraries\TeamSpeak3\Helper\String.php on line 192
```

That warning only shows up with some server groups, I don't know the reason.

---

```
$admins = 0;
foreach($ts3->clientList($client) as $client) {
    $admins++;
}
```

I guess this piece of code should show all online users but I tested it and the value is not always the online users, like I said before on my virtual server it shows the right count but when I tried it on another virtual server I got 48 but there are 61 users online.

Answer (score 2):

I know that was one year ago but that might help because I was Googling the same question and after some time I found out how to do it.

Here's what you are looking for, tested it and works:

```
   foreach($ts3_VirtualServer->serverGroupClientList(11) as $admins){
        foreach($arr_ClientList as $ts3_Client)
            if(in_array($ts3_Client['client_nickname'], $admins)){
                $adminsCount++;
            }
    }
```

Hope it will help ;)